# WinError 32, Python, file used by another process

Tags: python, windows, file-handling, shutil, rar

I have a script that is searching through files in a folder for multiple functions, one of which is verifying if they are valid.  If they are corrupt, it moves them to another location.  When trying to move the file, I get an error that it is being used by another process.  I've looked through other similar questions, but none seem to resolve my issue.

```
path = filedialog.askdirectory()
pathbad = filedialog.askdirectory()
conv = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path))
bad = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(pathbad))

jpg_list = []
badfiles = []
nojpg = []

cbz_list = [str(pp) for pp in path.glob("**/*.cbz")]
cbr_list = [str(pp) for pp in path.glob("**/*.cbr")]
file_list = cbr_list + cbz_list

for file in file_list:
   if ('.cbr' in file) or ('.rar' in file):
      try:
         with rarfile.RarFile(file) as MyRar:
            rarcontents = MyRar.namelist()
            rarcontents = [x.lower() for x in rarcontents]
            if any('.jpg' in s for s in rarcontents):
               jpg_list.append(file)
            else:
               nojpg.append(file)
      except (rarfile.BadRarFile):
         badfiles.append(file)
      except:
         continue

   if len(badfiles) > 0:
      print('Moving ', len(badfiles), ' bad archives to "Bad Files":\n')
      for zfile in badfiles:
         nfile = zfile.replace(conv, bad)
         shutil.move(zfile, nfile)
```

It errors on the shutil.move command.  The file is actually copied to the new location, but not deleted from the old.  I have verified that the file is not open in any application outside of python, and the only place it's open in python uses a with statement, which (as I understand it) closes the file when complete.

Edit:
Complete Stack Trace

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 806, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Q:\\Download\\Comics\\Various Files\\Convert\\Poptropica 01.cbr' -> 'Q:\\Download\\Comics\\Various Files\\Bad Files\\Poptropica 01.cbr'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\azure\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1105858891\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\azure\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1105858891\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\azure\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1105858891\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "i:\dev\comix\cbz_JPG-to-WEBP.py", line 138, in <module>
    shutil.move(zfile, nfile)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 827, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Q:\\Download\\Comics\\Various Files\\Convert\\Poptropica 01.cbr'
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete stack trace of the error.

Answer (score -2):

1. If you are on windows open the task manager and close the python prosseses
2. Restart PC

Comment: Just tried that and still have the same issue after a reboot.  I have also tested, both before and after running the script that I am able to manually move the file between the two directories in question with no errors.